# How to import METADATA_PROGRAM_ID. (Buildspace Solana Staking Anchor course)

Tags: anchor, metaplex, staking, typescript, spl

I'm doing the Anchor Staking part of the solana Buildspace course. I get this error when running the first test:

> ReferenceError: METADATA_PROGRAM_ID is not defined

This is the Anchor Smartcontract I deployed:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed;
use anchor_spl::token;
use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    token::{Approve, Mint, MintTo, Revoke, Token, TokenAccount},
};
use mpl_token_metadata::{
    instruction::{freeze_delegated_account, thaw_delegated_account},
    ID as MetadataTokenId,
};

declare_id!("HyHEFjePsfdvToLSAfGXpE8CYS2V7GD4f75jGhPt4btx");

#[program]
pub mod anchor_nft_staking {
    use super::*;

    pub fn stake(ctx: Context<Stake>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }


}


#[account]
pub struct UserStakeInfo {
    pub token_account: Pubkey,
    pub stake_start_time: i64,
    pub last_stake_redeem: i64,
    pub user_pubkey: Pubkey,
    pub stake_state: StakeState,
    pub is_initialized: bool,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, AnchorDeserialize, AnchorSerialize, Clone)]
pub enum StakeState {
    Unstaked,
    Staked,
}

impl Default for StakeState {
    fn default() -> Self {
        StakeState::Unstaked
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Metadata;

impl anchor_lang::Id for Metadata {
    fn id() -> Pubkey {
        MetadataTokenId
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Stake<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        associated_token::mint=nft_mint,
        associated_token::authority=user
    )]
    pub nft_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub nft_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    /// CHECK: Manual validation
    #[account(owner=MetadataTokenId)]
    pub nft_edition: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer=user,
        space = std::mem::size_of::<UserStakeInfo>() + 8,
        seeds = [user.key().as_ref(), nft_token_account.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub stake_state: Account<'info, UserStakeInfo>,
    /// CHECK: Manual validation
    #[account(mut, seeds=["authority".as_bytes().as_ref()], bump)]
    pub program_authority: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
}
```

This is the utils/setupnft.ts file:

```
import {
    bundlrStorage,
    keypairIdentity,
    Metaplex,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/js"
import { createMint, getAssociatedTokenAddress } from "@solana/spl-token"
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor"

export const setupNft = async (program, payer) => {
    const metaplex = Metaplex.make(program.provider.connection)
        .use(keypairIdentity(payer))
        .use(bundlrStorage())

    const nft = await metaplex
        .nfts()
        .create({
            uri: "",
            name: "Test nft",
            sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
        })

    console.log("nft metadata pubkey: ", nft.metadataAddress.toBase58())
    console.log("nft token address: ", nft.tokenAddress.toBase58())
    const [delegatedAuthPda] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [Buffer.from("authority")],
        program.programId
    )
    const [stakeStatePda] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [payer.publicKey.toBuffer(), nft.tokenAddress.toBuffer()],
        program.programId
    )

    console.log("delegated authority pda: ", delegatedAuthPda.toBase58())
    console.log("stake state pda: ", stakeStatePda.toBase58())
    const [mintAuth] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [Buffer.from("mint")],
        program.programId
    )

    const mint = await createMint(
        program.provider.connection,
        payer,
        mintAuth,
        null,
        2
    )
    console.log("Mint pubkey: ", mint.toBase58())

    const tokenAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint, payer.publicKey)

    return {
        nft: nft,
        delegatedAuthPda: delegatedAuthPda,
        stakeStatePda: stakeStatePda,
        mint: mint,
        mintAuth: mintAuth,
        tokenAddress: tokenAddress,
    }
}
```

And this is the testfile:

```
import { PublicKey } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { AnchorNftStaking } from "../target/types/anchor_nft_staking";
import { setupNft } from "./utils/setupNft";


describe("anchor-nft-staking", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());


  const wallet = anchor.workspace.AnchorNftStaking.provider.wallet
  const program = anchor.workspace.AnchorNftStaking as Program<AnchorNftStaking>;



  let delegatedAuthPda: anchor.web3.PublicKey
  let stakeStatePda: anchor.web3.PublicKey
  let nft: any
  let mintAuth: anchor.web3.PublicKey
  let mint: anchor.web3.PublicKey
  let tokenAddress: anchor.web3.PublicKey

  before(async () => {
    ; ({ nft, delegatedAuthPda, stakeStatePda, mint, mintAuth, tokenAddress } =
      await setupNft(program, wallet.payer))
  })

  it("Stakes", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    await program.methods
      .stake()
      .accounts({
        nftTokenAccount: nft.tokenAddress,
        nftMint: nft.mintAddress,
        nftEdition: nft.masterEditionAddress,
        metadataProgram: METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
      .rpc()

  })
});
```

I copied it all from the course, but can't find how to define the  METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.

Did I forget to copy something? Or did I do something wrong?
Is this the general metaplex metadata program id?
It doesn't work when I define it as a string ("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s" )
Or has it something to do with my smartcontract?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata) and import it like

```
import { PROGRAM_ID as METADATA_PROGRAM_ID } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata"
```

Else you can declare it yourself

```
const METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s");
```